# Service é interrompido quando executado no BOOT_COMPLETED

Tags: android

Pessoal estava fazendo um exemplo para um serviço de uma aplicação ser inicia no boot, ele parece iniciar mas se interrompe em poucos segundos e não consigo entender porque, estou seguindo um exemplo de um livro, e encontrei a mesma coisa em muitos exemplos quase igual. Alguma dica pois não consigo entender porque o serviço é interrompido.

```java
public class NotificacaoTask extends TimerTask {

    private static int i = 0;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Log.i("servico" ,"Incremento: "+ i++);

    }
 }
```

```java
public class Servico extends Service {

 public static final String CATEGORIA = "servico";
 public Timer timer;

@Override

 public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Log.i("servico","O servico foi iniciado!!!!");
    timer = new Timer();
    long delayInicial = 1 * 1000; //segundos
    long periodo = (long) 1 * 1000;

    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new NotificacaoTask() ,  delayInicial, periodo );
    return START_STICKY;
 }


public void onDestroy(){
    Log.i("servico" , "servico destruido");
    timer.cancel();
    super.onDestroy();
}


@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

}
```

```java
public class BootReciever extends BroadcastReceiver {

public static Intent service;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    service = new Intent("INICIAR_SERVICO");

    context.startService( service );

    Log.i("servico","iniciou serviço boot");

}
}
```

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />


<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.serviceboot.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>


    <service android:name="Servico">
     <intent-filter>
     <action android:name="INICIAR_SERVICO" />
     <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
     </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <receiver android:name="BootReciever">
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

</application>
```

saida logcat

```
04-08 18:37:47.036: I/servico(704): iniciou serviço boot
04-08 18:37:47.057: I/servico(704): O servico foi iniciado!!!!
04-08 18:37:48.077: I/servico(704): Incremento: 0
04-08 18:37:49.186: I/servico(704): Incremento: 1
04-08 18:37:50.166: I/servico(704): Incremento: 2
04-08 18:37:51.077: I/servico(704): Incremento: 3
04-08 18:37:52.077: I/servico(704): Incremento: 4
04-08 18:37:53.077: I/servico(704): Incremento: 5
04-08 18:37:54.085: I/servico(704): Incremento: 6
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O que me parece estar acontecendo é o seguinte: seu serviço cria uma instância (objeto) de `Timer` chamada `timer`, porém essa instância só irá durar enquanto o Service estiver sendo executado, depois disso não haverá mais ninguém referenciando essa instância e ela será apagada pelo *garbage collector*. E de fato, o seu `Service` é executado após o *boot* e finaliza em seguida (não há nenhum motivo para que não termine de executar, pois não existe um *loop* nele ou qualquer outro comando de execução mais prolongada - não pense que `timer.scheduleAtFixedRate()` fica paradinho esperando as tasks executarem) e, quando o serviço finaliza, a instância de `Timer` é *garbage-collected* pouco depois.

(Note que mesmo se isso não acontecer, a linha `timer.cancel();` no método `onDestroy()` irá fazer o `timer` ser cancelado e as *tasks* pararem de executar do mesmo jeito).

A solução nesse caso seria guardar a referência a `Timer` em uma variável de maior duração, como por exemplo uma variável estática.

Porém, o jeito mais certo de fazer, se você quer programar o seu aparelho para executar uma tarefa de tempos em tempos, é não usar `TimerTask` e sim fazer o método `onReceive()` do seu *broadcast receiver* agendar a execução periódica de um serviço por meio do [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) (você usa essa classe para programar a execução de um serviço de uma maneira parecida como programou a execução da `TimerTask`. Mas não estou sendo preciso: o que na verdade acontece é que o `AlarmManager` irá chamar um outro *broadcast receiver*, que esse sim chamará o serviço que você quer executar). Lendo assim parece complicado, mas é simples - tem um link abaixo com um exemplo. Fazendo desse jeito, que é o jeito "Android" de fazer, após o *boot* o aparelho irá executar o serviço desejado de tempos em tempos.

**Dica:** Programando a execução do serviço dessa maneira, provavelmente você irá querer definir seu serviço como uma subclasse de [IntentService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) e sobrescrever seu método [onHandleIntent()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html#onHandleIntent%28android.content.Intent%29), que executa tarefas em um *thread* secundário. Isso porque a classe básica `Service` executa no *thread* principal (também chamado *thread* de *UI*), que não deve ser sobrecarregado com tarefas demoradas porque é responsável por atualizar a tela.

**Links úteis:**

- [Como definir alarmes recorrentes](http://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html) de acordo com a documentação oficial (em inglês)
- [Exemplo simples de AlarmManager](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/use-androids-alarmmanager-to-schedule-an-event/) (em inglês)

Comment: Valeu utilizando AlertManager funcionou beleza, mas ficou uma pequena dúvida, no meu Servico quando ele termina normalmente ele não chama onDestroy() ? ou onDestroy() só é chamado por stopService()

Comment: @user4438 Se não me engano, a chamada a onDestroy() não é garantida de ser executada. Melhor não contar com ela em todas as situações.